# Why we express the radiation pattern of an antenna array in terms of electric field and not magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, antennas

Is this because in the farzone we are talking about TEM waves and the relation of the magnitude of the field is E=ηH, therefore the patterns of the fields should be identical in terms of shape and differ only by a factor η?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radiation pattern of an antenna is the radiation intensity $S = E \times H$ usually plotted in spherical angle coordinates (azimuth, elevation) be it far or near field. It is always a relative measurement normalized to some reference radiation value for the *radiated* intensity is proportional to the actual (actual=incident $-$ reflected $-$ absorbed) transmitted power at the antenna input. Because in a linear medium $E$ and $H$ are proportional, therefore $S \propto E^2 \propto H^2$, and a radiation pattern represents all three $S$, $E^2$ an $H^2$.